# In pipeline YAML of a NodeJS project referring to another project for deployment

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a NodeJS Rest API project.
I have also an Ansible project for deploying the above NodeJS project to our server (not in cloud).

We are using Bitbucket pipeline.

My goal is to setup a pipeline in the NodeJS project repo so that when a code merge happened from `feature` branch to `develop` branch, it would automatically trigger a deployment via the Ansible project.

Since it is a cross-project automation pipeline, could someone guide me how to achieve it?

I can come up with the following skeleton:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Deploy using Ansible
          deployment: production
          script:
            - ansible-playbook -i ansible-project/inventory ansible-project/playbook.yml
```

But what puzzles me is that above pipeline is in the NodeJS project repo,  how can I refer to another project repo (the `ansible-project`) to run the playbook in this pipeline?

Is it achievable even?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [pipeline trigger](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/trigger-pipeline) in the pipeline for the NodeJS project to trigger a pipeline to run in the ansible project to run your deploy.

It will take some configuration with [access tokens](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/access-tokens/) to set it up, you will need an access token in the NodeJS project that has write permission to the ansible-project bitbucket repo.

Answer (score 0):

To make one pipeline execute something from a different repository (ansible) but with files from the current repository (playbook) you have a couple of options:

- use `git(1)` and checkout what you want, where you want it and then process the checkout result.
- use HTTPS requests to send API requests and receive responses. Your repositories, your pipelines, all them have a REST API.
- turn a repository into a pipe (e.g. the ansible one) then execute the playbook in that pipe (caveat: not all runners support pipes).

mix and match these options for your success. normally I recommend to start with plain git, as especially in bitbucket pipelines you can easily start with scripts in your scripts. extra docker containers, which includes pipes, I'd do later if even necessary.

running other pipes only to trigger those things is most indirect and therefore I'd not recommend it, however if it works for you, go with what you can get working first.

---

Reference:

- [Access multiple Bitbucket repositories from a single Pipeline by
  Michael Atkinson on Aug 20, 2021](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Access-multiple-Bitbucket-repositories-from-a-single-Pipeline/qaq-p/1783419)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you can clone the external repo into your current pipeline and placing it in some defined folder. Then you need to build a BASH script to execute custom CI or CD Action.

You need to enforce the sequential step to do that using more step.